# Android Studio IDE Basics - different Colors on file name

Tags: android-studio, git-commit

[image]

Can Anyone explain what is the meaning of this different colors. Sometimes I also see Blue and green colors on file name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In IntelliJ IDEA, each file is marked with a color according to its state in the version control you are using. Android Studio is actually based on IntelliJ IDEA, but specializes in developing for the Android platform.

In the editor, each line in a file is checked for its version control state and is marked with a color in the gutter.

More about [File Status](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/file-status-highlights.html#views)

If you want to change the default file status colors, go to `Settings/Preferences | Version Control | File Status Colors`.